# default focus on tml page in Tapestry5

Tags: tapestry

Hi,
I am facing weird issue on my tapestry page.

On page I have three fields.
1st – select box -> tabindex is 1 and t:validate="required”
2nd – textfield -> tabindex is 2 and t:validate="required”
3rd – textfield -> tabindex is 3 and t:validate="required”

When my page gets load default focus is on 2nd textfield, but as per the tab index it has to be on select box.

To solve this issue I used below script on my tml page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {document.getElementById('id').focus();});
</script>
```

his is working pretty fine, on page load focus shifted from textfield to selectbox, but error balloon pops up on textfield.

Comment: Can you provide more info? Is the focus correct when the form is first rendered (before the submit)? After the submit, which fields have errors?

Comment: I am not submitting the form. facing the issue on page load.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `autofocus` attribute on the [Form](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Form.html) component.

"If true (the default), then the JavaScript will be added to position the cursor into the form. The field to receive focus is the first rendered field that is in error, or required, or present (in that order of priority)."

You might also be interested in [JavaScriptSupport.autoFocus(...)](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/javascript/JavaScriptSupport.html#autofocus%28org.apache.tapestry5.FieldFocusPriority,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: but the default value of autofocus is true. it means without using this field it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got the answer.

Here is the one liner solution. Just put the autofocus=”false” in form component, and yes it worked.

By default autofocus value is true and page put the focus on field depends on certain criteria, and some time behave weird.

Visit below link for more info.
http://tapestry.apache.org/forms-and-form-components-faq.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it's most likely caused by using an inline `<script>` to listen to the window's load event. Try firing your script via JavaScriptSupport instead. You may need to give it an InitializationPriority of LATE.

I'm still not sure why it's focusing on the text field instead of the select?

Comment: I can not use  JavaScriptSupport.autoFocus(...) method because i am using Tapestry 5.1.0.5 version. But i tried to call javascript method ,to set the default focus, from AfterRender method but it is not working.

Comment: can you please join the chat room so we can chat?   http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32020/tapestry

Comment: Have you tried JavascriptSupport.addScript(InitializationPriority.LATE, "document.getElementById('id').focus();");